# Loader screen not coming up and neither the result is getting printed by textview

Tags: android

I'm trying to generate the score of a name. So after the user inputs his name in the editText field 'name' and presses the button 'sub', the 'chk' button activates calculates the score and a loader screen with a delay of 4 seconds should be displayed after which the textview 'res' should display the new string.

```
import steelkiwi.com.library.DotsLoaderView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int x, sum=0;
String str,str2;
Button sub,chk;
EditText name;
TextView res;
DotsLoaderView dotsLoaderView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    chk = findViewById(R.id.check);
    sub = findViewById(R.id.submit);
    name = findViewById(R.id.name);
    res = findViewById(R.id.result);
    res.setText(R.string.result);
    dotsLoaderView = findViewById(R.id.dots_loader);
    chk.setEnabled(false);

    sub.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    str = name.getText().toString();
                    x = str.length();
                    if (x >= 4 && x <= 10)
                        chk.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
    chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i;
            for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                if (str.charAt(i) == 'a' || str.charAt(i) == 'A')
                    sum = sum + 1;
                else if (str.charAt(i) == 'b' || str.charAt(i) == 'B')
                    sum = sum + 2;
                else if (str.charAt(i) == 'c' || str.charAt(i) == 'C')
                    sum = sum + 3;
                               .
                               .
                               .
                else if (str.charAt(i) == 'z' || str.charAt(i) == 'Z')
                    sum = sum + 26;
            }
        }
    });
    str2 = "Hey "+str+" your score is "+ sum;
    downloadDemo();
}

private void downloadDemo() {
    AsyncTask<String, String, String> demoAsync = new AsyncTask<String, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dotsLoaderView.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return "done";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            if (s.equals("done"))
                dotsLoaderView.hide();

        }
    };
    demoAsync.execute();
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    res.setText(str2);
    }
}
```

But here. After pressing the 'chk' button, nothing is happening. And the 'res' box is just showing the @string/result value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str2 = "Hey "+str+" your score is "+ sum;
downloadDemo();
```

These lines are in your onCreate, not your ClickListener. Also, you don't do anything at all with the res box after you initialize it with R.string.result. So what's happening is, when you launch the Activity, the DotsLoaderView is being shown for four seconds, and the string "Hey  your score is 0" is being assigned to str2, and when you click the CHECK button, sum is calculated but nothing is done with it.